# Looking for ranges in dataframe values

Tags: r, dataframe, range

I have 2 dataframes:

```
> access
     V1     V2     V3
1 chr10 136122 136533
2 chr10 179432 179769
3 chr10 182988 183371
4 chr10 224234 224489
5 chr10 237693 237958
```

and

```
> peaks
     V1     V2     V3
1 chr10 126122 126533
2 chr10 179450 179730
3 chr10 182788 183350
4 chr10 224244 224500
5 chr10 237695 237950
```

The coloumn V2 and V3 are **start** and **end** of regions (range) in both dataframes. I want to keep those rows in `peaks` dataframe for which `access$V1 == peaks$V1` AND which fall in the  range (or regions) of `access` dataframe. For example the new dataframe will be like: `peaks` dataframe's

- 1st row region doesn't exist in `access` dataframe so it will be assigned category **U**.
- 2nd row of `peaks` falls in the given range in `access` dataframe (2nd row) and will be assigned category **B**.
- 3rd row of `peaks` doesn't completely fall in that region but it somehow overlaps with region in 3rd row of `access`, for this I will assign category **A**.
- 4th row of `peaks` also doesn't overlap completely at it ends 11 number after the end of region in row 4 of access, this will also be in category **A**.
- 5th row falls in the region hence will be in category **B**.

**Expected output:**

```
> newdf   
     V1     V2     V3 V4
1 chr10 126122 126533  U
2 chr10 179450 179730  B
3 chr10 182788 183350  A
4 chr10 224244 224500  A
5 chr10 237695 237950  B
```

Here are the dput of input dataframes:

```
> dput(peaks)
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr10", class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(126122L, 179450L, 182788L, 224244L, 237695L), V3 = c(126533L, 
    179730L, 183350L, 224500L, 237950L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

> dput(access)
    structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr10", class = "factor"), 
        V2 = c(136122L, 179432L, 182988L, 224234L, 237693L), V3 = c(136533L, 
        179769L, 183371L, 224489L, 237958L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
    "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**Edit:**

My new access df looks like this and now I also want to append the last column in my final output df:

```
> access
     V1     V2     V3  V4
1 chr10 136122 136533  found
2 chr10 179432 179769  notFound
3 chr10 182988 183371  found
4 chr10 224234 224489  found
5 chr10 237693 237958  notFound
```

So now there is one extra condition which is if row in access falls in peaks range then also append the value in V4 in a new column in final df, if some region is not found then by default will be `notFound`. Therefore, final output will be:

```
> newdf   
     V1     V2     V3 V4 V5
1 chr10 126122 126533  U notFound
2 chr10 179450 179730  B notFound
3 chr10 182788 183350  A found
4 chr10 224244 224500  A found
5 chr10 237695 237950  B notFound
```

Here in `row1$V5` the value is notFound because this region was not found and in remaining cases we got the values in V5 from modified access df.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [roll join with start/end window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window)

Comment: @zx8754 The difference is in that question it is just one number being checked if it exist in the range or not, **here I am searching for a range (not a number) with in an other range**.

Comment: @zx8754 `newdf <- subset(merge(access, peaks), start <= V2 & V3 <= end)` this is giving me only those which falls in those range, I am unable to figure out how to assign them the categories I defined and also how to keep those which do not completely fall in those ranges. Can you help me with this..?

Comment: This is exactly the case `foverlaps` was developed - with genetics regions overlap in mind. Read about `type` and `nomatch` arguments of the function.

Comment: @zx8754 I have tried but I am unable to do what I want. When I use `type= "all"`, I get rows which are within those ranges and also which overlaps but not exactly within that range, and when I use `type = "within"`, I only get rows which falls within given ranges. So I know I have to use `type= "all"` but I am not getting the idea how I can label those rows as per the categories I defined. Kindly help me in this context. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another (straightforward) solution using the non-equi joins implemented recently and available in the current development version of data.table, v1.9.7. See installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
setDT(access)
setDT(peaks)[, V4 := "U"]                              # no overlap
peaks[access, V4 := "A", on=.(V1, V2 <= V3, V3 >= V2)] # any overlap
peaks[access, V4 := "B", on=.(V1, V2 >= V2, V3 <= V3)] # completly within
#       V1     V2     V3 V4
# 1: chr10 126122 126533  U
# 2: chr10 179450 179730  B
# 3: chr10 182788 183350  A
# 4: chr10 224244 224500  A
# 5: chr10 237695 237950  B
```

Add a new column to `peaks` which is all "U". Then replace those rows where there's any kind of overlap with "A". That would contain all rows which are also completely *"within"*. Then once again, perform a conditional join, but this time only for completely within, and replace with "B".

---

Note that the `foverlaps()` solution would work just fine as well (it also comes from data.table package). But the new non-equi joins fits well with the `[.data.table` syntax which allows to aggregate/add/update cols *while joining*.

Comment: Kindly confirm if I am not wrong, they are like: `peaks[access, V4 := "A", on=.(peaks$V1, peaks$V2 <= access$V3, peaks$V3 >= access$V2)]` AND `peaks[access, V4 := "B", on=.(peaks$V1, peaks$V2 >= access$V2, peaks$V3 <= access$V3)]`

Comment: You got it right. LHS of expression refers to DT on the outside.

Comment: I have modified the question, see an Edit above, can you please suggest me how can I solve this new problem? Thanks.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working: `peaks[access, V5 := access$V4, on=.(peaks$V1, peaks$V2 <= access$V3, peaks$V3 >= access$V2)]`

Comment: Replace `access$V4` with `i.V4` (i refers to the first argument, here `access`). Remove all the `...$` in the `on=` argument. Variables can be referred directly by names. `on` argument doesn't understand what `...$` is. [Read the vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) to get an idea about data.table's features / philosophy.

Comment: In the `on` argument, you will be able to do `x.V1 <= i.V1` etc.. where `x` refers the data.table on the outside, and `i` is the first argument, but it's not implemented yet. This is a new feature.

Comment: In your answer can you modify how can I select those bins which are completely overlapping with my regions (not within, but completely overlapping as they are bigger). For example my bin is from 200-400 and overlapping region is 150-450. So how can I assign them "B"?

Comment: Can you please suggest me a solution for this problem? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187739/r-processing-the-input-file-based-on-range-overlap

Answer (score 1):

If speed is a concern, the linked `data.table` solution will probably be superior, but it can also be achieved in `dplyr`, but likely much slower:

```
library(dplyr)
names(access)[2:3] <- c('start', 'end')

bind_cols(peaks[-1], access) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(V4 = if_else(all(V2:V3 %in% start:end), 'B',
                      if_else(any(V2:V3 %in% start:end), 'A',
                              'U')))
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 5 x 6
      V2     V3     V1  start    end    V4
   <int>  <int> <fctr>  <int>  <int> <chr>
1 126122 126533  chr10 136122 136533     U
2 179450 179730  chr10 179432 179769     B
3 182788 183350  chr10 182988 183371     A
4 224244 224500  chr10 224234 224489     A
5 237695 237950  chr10 237693 237958     B
```

Comment: which packages are you using here because I am getting following error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "if_else"` and if I use `ifelse` instead from base then I get multiple warning and the categories for all rows are **U**

Comment: `dplyr` version `0.5.0`. `if_else` is not in earlier versions.

Comment: I have got an error when I applied it to my real data where no.of rows are different in 2 dataframes: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  incompatible number of rows (103335, expecting 90)` Can you guide me how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Use left_join instead of bind_cols.

Comment: Can you please help me with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501840/dataframe-processing)

Answer (score 1):

Though its a long way of doing it. But it gives the desired results.

```
library(dplyr)
df<-cbind(peaks,access) #merging both df
colnames(df)<-c("pV1","pV2","pV3","aV1","aV2","aV3")
df<-df[c(which(df$pV1==df$aV1)),] # selecting rows with pV1=aV1
# creating U, A, B
U1<-df%>%
   filter(pV2<aV2 & pV3<aV2)%>%
   mutate(V4="U")
U2<-df%>%
  filter(pV2>aV3 & pV3>aV3)%>%
  mutate(V4="U")
B<-df%>%
 filter(pV2>aV2 & pV3<aV3)%>%
   mutate(V4="B")
A1<-df%>%
   filter(pV2>aV2 & pV3>aV3)%>%
   mutate(V4="A")
A2<-df%>%
   filter(pV2<aV2 & pV3<aV3 & pV3>aV2)%>%
   mutate(V4="A")
#merging U, A and B into newdf
newdf<-arrange(rbind(U1,U2,B,A1,A2),pV2)
newdf<-newdf[,-c(4:6)]
newdf
    pV1    pV2    pV3 V4
1 chr10 126122 126533  U
2 chr10 179450 179730  B
3 chr10 182788 183350  A
4 chr10 224244 224500  A
5 chr10 237695 237950  B
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the foverlaps function it can be done with the following statement:

```
setkey(setDT(access),V1,V2,V3)
setkey(setDT(peaks),V1,V2,V3)

access[,V4:= ifelse(!is.na(foverlaps(peaks, access, type="within", which=TRUE)$yid),"B",ifelse(!is.na( foverlaps(peaks, access, type="any", which=TRUE)$yid),"A","U"))]
```

The way it functions is the following:

1. I first use the "within" type to determine if there is an exact overlap (so if a range is included in any of the matching access ranges.If it is the case then "B"
2. If this is not the case, I use the "any" to determine if we have any overlap which practically identifies the values that have a partial overlap since the values with exact overlap were excluded in the previous step. These values get an "A"
3. The rest gets a "U"

Comment: Can you please help me with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501840/dataframe-processing)